# Prove that $W$ and $(M,)$ are independent (see the referenced post)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Following the question asked here :
[Express the event ${W≤w,M= 1,O≤t}$ in terms of the random variables $X$ and $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036962/express-the-event-w%e2%89%a4w-m-1-o%e2%89%a4t-in-terms-of-the-random-variables-x-and-y)

I recall the notation
$X, Y \sim \exp (\lambda)$,
$W=\min (X, Y)$,
$Z=\max (X, Y)$,
$O=Z-W$,
and $M=1_{X \leq Y}$.

I am asked to prove that $W$ and $(M,O)$ are independent.

I have been given the **Hint** You may assume without proof that it is enough to check that $P((W\in A, (M,O)\in B )= P((W\in  A) P( (M,0) ∈ B)$,  for $A= [0,w] and B={m}×[0,t]$, for all $w\ge0$, $m ∈ \{0,1\}$ and $t\ge0$

However, it appears this hint considers the same events-  $(W\le w, M=1, O\le t)$ and  $(W\le w, M=0, O\le t)$
as discussed in the link, which is calculated via a double integral, which can of course be split and computed  as $2$ separate integrals multiplied together, immediately implying the proof (see hint), so I'm not sure why this question would be asked (by the lecturer), after asking the previous question, which is:

Find $(W\le w, M=1, O\le t)$ and  $(W\le w, M=0, O\le t)$  (see the referenced post).

Any help would be much appreciated

Thankyou

Comment: Hi there, please type the important mathematical content with Mathjax, even if it appears in a previous post. I know [you said](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33205/prove-that-w-and-m-o-are-independent) you followed the advice, but please use Mathjax. This helps users with slow connections, poor eyesight, or maybe imgur is blocked in their workplace. You can get started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Okay, I’ll will take a look to Mathjax for my next post, thanks for the help Calvin ! I have now resolved my question, how do I mark it as “Solved” or “Complete” ? Thanks again

Comment: Normally, you would wait until you get an Answer, and then if you agree with it, you can click on a tick ✅ to the left to Accept it as solving your problem. Unfortunately, you did not receive an Answer on the site yet. What you can do (besides waiting for an answer) is Answer your own Question, then Accept it. (I don't do a lot of probability, so I didn't attempt to answer the question!)

Comment: Ah I see ! Thankyou